# Using Entity framework across multiple tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-5

I am trying to a linq statement where I have the following four tables

```
table: plan
id
planname

table: patient 
Fields
id, firstname, lastname, site_id

Table: site
id,
sitename

table: plan_patient
id
site_id
patient_id

table: plan_Exclusions
id
patient_id
plan_id
site_id

table: plan_schedule
id
patient_id
plan_id
site_id
```

I want to pull back all of the patients that have not been assigned to a plan or excluded from the plan.

what determines if a patient is not assigned to a plan, is that they are in the exclusion table, they don't have a schedule in the `plan_schedule` table and they don't exist in the `plan_patient` table.

This is so easy to do in a stored procedure, but I am trying to build this out, so that I don't need to do a stored procedure to pull back the results.

Comment: Why did you separate your plan_patient, plan_exclusion, and plan_schedule columns into new tables? All the other table columns are identical.

Comment: It would help to know what the classes look like, especially the navigation properties.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have reached out to multiple tables for a complex

```
var MyResults =
   from hc in context.hcTypes
   from hga in context.hgaToGmuTypes
   from hq in context.hqToQuota
   from qt in context.Types
   from dd in context.ddDraws
   from dh in context.dhDraws
   where hc.Year == dtYear
        && hc.Year == hga.Year
       && hc.code == hga.code
       && hc.Year == hq.Year
       && hc.code == hq.code
       && hq.Id == qt.Id
       && qt.PrefernceCode == "Y"
       && hga.Year == dtYear
       && hga.Code == "Z"
       && hc.code == dd.code
       && dd.Code == dh.Code
       && dh.Year == dtYear
       && dh.Code == "Z" 
       && dh.Left == "P"
select new MyClass { Id = hc.Id, Huntcode = hc.Huntcode, GMU = hga.GMUTypeCode }
 ;
```

In your case, it would be something like:

```
var YourResults = 
    from pl in plan 
    from pa in patient 
    from s = site 
    from plan_patient 
    from plan_Exclusions 

    with the Where statements linking the data 
    and the Select pulling what you want
```